# JSON_ENCODE LARAVEL No Work

Tags: laravel

Do not return my json_encode page after I access the button. I do not know why.
SkinID data is saved correctly. Only the return does not work.

```
public function buy()
{
    $player = \Auth::user();
    $player->SkinID = $_POST['id'];
    $player->save();
    return json_encode(['type' => 'success','title' => 'TEST BOX','text' => 'TEST MESSAGE LARAVEL!']);
}
```

app.min.js:

```
$("._buy").click(function() {
    var o = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: _PAGE_URL + "api/buy",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: o
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: i see no callback/then to handle the response of the ajax

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Where is _PAGE_URL defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel built in function to return json:

```
 return response()
         ->json(['type' => 'success','title' => 'TEST BOX','text' => 'TEST MESSAGE LARAVEL!']);
```